# Class not found when using SwingUtilities.invokeLater in OSGi Bundle

Tags: java, swing, osgi, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater

(EDIT: Problem is solved - see details at the end)

I want to create a Swing `JFrame` with a `WindowAdapter` in an OSGi Bundle. When I do this using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, the `WindowAdapter` class is not found. Without `invokeLater` it works.

What do I need to do so that `WindowAdapter` is found when using `invokeLater`?
Is `invokeLater` inappropriate in an OSGi environment?

The details:

I start an Apache Felix framework instance with my custom launcher, install the bundle and start it. My bundle's start method looks like this:

```
public void start(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {
    myFrame = new MyFrame();
    myFrame.open();
}
```

This is the MyFrame class:

```
public class MyFrame {
    JFrame mainFrame;

    public void open() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                openImpl();
            }
        });
        // If called like this it works:
        // openImpl();
    }

    public void openImpl() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Title");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        WindowAdapter wa = new WindowAdapter() {
        };
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(wa);
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is my manifest for the bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_03-b05 (Oracle Corporation)
Built-By: Rainer Schwarze
Bundle-Name: DummyBdl
Bundle-Description: Dummy Bundle
Bundle-Vendor: admaDIC
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1
Bundle-Activator: dummybdl.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, javax.swing
Export-Package: dummybdl.api
Export-Service: dummybdl.Provider
```

And this is the stack trace which I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at dummybdl.MyFrame.openImpl(MyFrame.java:24)
    at dummybdl.MyFrame$1.run(MyFrame.java:16)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Being an OSGi newbie I tried several things to fix it, but couldn't find a solution so far. So why not make my first question at StackOverflow :-)

EDIT:

After debugging for half an hour it turns out that the problem was entirely mine:
My code stopped the OSGi framework before `openImpl` gets called in the EDT.

So the Apache Felix framework marked the `BundleWiringImpl` instance (see stack trace) as disposed. When my `openImpl` gets called in the EDT, `BundleWiringImpl.getClassLoader` returns `null` because it is marked as disposed. Eventually this leads to the NPE.
(I should have gone the extra steps of posting the 50 lines of my Felix loader which might have made the error obvious.)

Comment: If you code is accurate, then line MyFrame.java:24 is "new JFrame()", so the class that's failing to load is presumably javax.swing.JFrame. I am really stumped by this. I thought about it for a long time...

Comment: If I've got the write jar versions, then line 1432 of BundleWiringImpl is this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/4.0.2/org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl.java?av=h#1432, which means that either the getClassLoader() is returning null or m_revision is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code stopped the OSGi framework before `openImpl` gets called in the EDT.

Without `invokeLater` `openImpl` is called immediately and before my other code shuts down the OSGi framework. With `invokeLater` the call to `openImpl` is scheduled for later and before that "later" happens, my code shuts down the OSGi framework.

In that case the Apache Felix framework marked the `BundleWiringImpl` instance (see stack trace) as disposed. When my `openImpl` gets called in the EDT, `BundleWiringImpl.getClassLoader` returns `null` because it is marked as disposed. Eventually this leads to the NPE.

Comment: (Found out that self answering is acceptable and decided to move my question out of the unanswered pool...)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>*The answer* The `WindowAdapter` class you try to use is located in `java.awt.event`, but you don't import that package.</strike> Edit: this did not seem to fix the problem (see comments), but the backstory below remains.

*The backstory* Your manifest looks hand-crafted, I would advise you not to do that (you'll make mistakes, and it's a hassle to keep the manifest nicely in sync). Take a look at [bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) if you're using Eclipse, or plain [bnd](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd) for any other environment.

Comment: When I add `java.awt.event` to Import-Package I get: `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Importing java.* packages not allowed: java.awt.event`.

Comment: Ooh, good point, I totally missed that. Still, I stick with my point that you shouldn't build the manifest by hand, but let a tool do that. I'll update my answer for this.

Comment: I tried bndtools to see whether it does some magic which my newbie understanding does not cover. However the relevant MANIFEST entries are the same and the Exception is still thrown. In the meantime I found an interesting article which may address the issue. I'll read that when I get a little spare time in a few hours and post updates.

Answer (score -1):

The stacktrace contains some security checks "ProtectionDomain,..doIntersectionPrivilege".
Have you tried to disable the SecurityManager. you can disable is with following VM option:

-Djava.security.manager=

Look also here:
[How to disable Java security manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762459/how-to-disable-java-security-manager)

Comment: I started my application with `-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=java.policy` and put `grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };` in the policy file. Still the same stack trace. Without the policy file parameter I get `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied  ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createSecurityManager")`. Hmmm.