# Load your own SecurityManager or disable existing

Tags: java

I want to load my own `java.lang.String`

```
public class StringCustomClassFactory {
    public static String newInstance() {
        URLClassLoader tmp = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///home/.../target/classes/") }) {
            public Class loadClass(String name) {
                if ("java.lang.String".equals(name))
                        return findClass(name);
                    return super.loadClass(name);
                    //exception handling is omitted 
            }
        };
return (String) tmp.loadClass("java.lang.String").newInstance();
//...
```

But I constantly receive exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
```

- In this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html) I've read that it possible to load your own SecurityManager

> The security of the system can be compromised if your class loader
>   returned its own value of java.lang.SecurityManager, which did not
>   have the same checks as the real one did.

- And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762459/how-to-disable-java-security-manager) I have read that it possible to disable SecurityManger

What would you recommend me to solve this problem and is it solvable at all?

Comment: First of all you should try to explain _why_ you need to do this, perhaps there are alternatives like AOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, and never will be able to, override classes in a package starting with `java.`; it has nothing to do with a SecurityManager, but instead it's enforced in `ClassLoader::preDefineClass`

Considering it means something is Very Wrong(tm) with the line of reasoning you're following; could you explain exactly why you need this?